# React says I'm performing a state update on an unmounted component, but my component (appears to be) mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

Forgive me, because I know that I'm the one causing this error but I don't know how - I'm new to React.

I have a component that is as best I can tell mounted. The component fetches a list of popular repositories from GitHub. The component effectively allows you to filter the list of repos that are returned by language. The component uses the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method to fire a request to the GitHub API. After that point, clicking on the different Nav elements fires requests to the GitHub API. The returned lists of repos are cached in state.

It seems important to note that the error is only occurring on page load and refresh. Sending new requests to the 3rd party API to fetch a new list of repos does not produce the error. Adding to my confusion is the fact that the app apparently functions fine - on page load, I get the correctly rendered list of repos (which are displayed in some card components).

The component itself is:

```
export default class Popular extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedLanguage: 'All',
    repos: {},
    error: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateLanguage(this.state.selectedLanguage)
  }

  updateLanguage = (selectedLanguage) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedLanguage,
      error: null
    })

    if (!this.state.repos[selectedLanguage]) {
      fetchPopularRepos(selectedLanguage)
        .then(data => {
          this.setState(({ repos }) => ({
            repos: {
              ...repos,
              [selectedLanguage]: data,
            }
          }))
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.warn('Error fetching repos: ')

          this.setState({
            error: 'There was an error fetching the repositories.'
          })
        })
    }
  }

  isLoading = () => {
    const { selectedLanguage, repos, error } = this.state;

    return !repos[selectedLanguage] && error === null
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedLanguage, repos, error } = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <LanguagesNav
          selected={selectedLanguage}
          onUpdateLanguage={this.updateLanguage}
        />

        {this.isLoading() && <Loading text='Fetching Repos' />}

        {error && <p className='center-text error'>{error}</p>}

        {repos[selectedLanguage] && <ReposGrid repos={repos[selectedLanguage]} />}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

In the browser, I'm getting a "cant perform state update on unmounted component" and the React Dev Tools are indicating that the error is coming from the `setState` in the promise returned from the `fetchPopularRepos` call.

The fetching from the third party API is accomplished as shown below:

```js
export function fetchPopularRepos(language) {
  const endpoint = window.encodeURI(`https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:${language}&sort=stars&order=desc&type=Repositories `);

  return fetch(endpoint)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (!data.items) {
        throw new Error(data.message)
      }

      return data.items
    })
}
```

And my index.js where the App component is being rendered:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    theme: 'light',
    toggleTheme: () => {
      this.setState(({ theme }) => ({
        theme: theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
      }))
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <ThemeProvider value={this.state}>
          <div className={this.state.theme}>
            <div className='container'>
              <Nav />

              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Popular} />
                <Route exact path='/battle' component={Battle} />
                <Route path='/battle/results' component={Results} />
                <Route component={NotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

EDIT: Added screenshot of stack trace.
EDIT 2: Added Router/index.js file

Comment: It's probably unmounted and mounted again quickly!

Comment: Can you show your router please?

Comment: Yes, will edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

I have done what your doing before, and This is because of `ThemeProvider`.

You are setting `ThemeProvider`'s theme inside `Router`.

Try define `ThemeProvider` outside the `Router` in other component:

App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    theme: 'light',
    toggleTheme: () => {
      this.setState(({ theme }) => ({
        theme: theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
      }))
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider value={this.state}>
          <div className={this.state.theme}>
            <Routes />
          </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

Routes.js:

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Popular} />
            <Route exact path="/battle" component={Battle} />
            <Route path="/battle/results" component={Results} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the issue.